# Vercel NextJS App Environement Variables Not Working

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, vercel

Coming from Ruby on Rails, I found it really hard to grasp the concept of environment variables on NextJS, specifically on Vercell platform. I followed [the NextJS documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#environment-variables-on-vercel) that recommends the Vercell documentation to set up the environment variables in their project settings even for development environments. So I did and pull them with `vercel env pull .env.local`. But when I run the development server, the process.env variables are always undefined. Found plenty of SO questions about this with no luck so far.

Example code that I use:

```
export function getEncodedClientIdAndSecret(): string {
    const clientId = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
    const clientSecret = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;

    if (!clientId || !clientSecret) {
        throw new Error('Missing client ID or client secret');
    }

    const encodedString = Buffer.from(`${clientId}:${clientSecret}`).toString('base64');
    return `Basic ${encodedString}`;
}
```

`.env.local` file:

```
# Created by Vercel CLI
REDIRECT_URI=localhost:3000/api/callback
BASE_URL=localhost:3000
FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL=projectid.firebaseio.com
FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL=dfsdfo@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com
FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY_B64=longenccryptedprivatekey
FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=projectid
CLIENT_SECRET=secreiclient
CLIENT_ID=clientid
```

I'm not a fan of JavaScript. This is really confusing.

Comment: Locally, what does your `.env.local` file look like? Also, is `getEncodedClientIdAndSecret` getting called on the client-side (browser) or server-side?

Comment: Here it is:

``` lang-js
# Created by Vercel CLI
REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:3000/api/callback
BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000
FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL=https://projectid.firebaseio.com
FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL=dfsdfo@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com
FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY_B64=longenccryptedprivatekey
FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=projectid
CLIENT_SECRET=secreiclient
CLIENT_ID=clientid
```

How to format the code in the comment?

Comment: Please add it to your question so you can properly format it.

Comment: Have you restarted the server ?

Comment: Yes. I tried it a couple times. I tried the NEXT_PUBLIC_ prefix as well. No luck. I'll try it again sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I run into this question again.

But this time, the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix from [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) works smoothly. I don't know why it didn't at that time when I tried that solution.

This is the working version of `.env` file:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIRECT_URI=<Callback URI from Spotify>
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=<Base URL of the project>
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID=<Spotify app client ID>
CLIENT_SECRET=<Spotify app client secret key>
FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=<Firebase project ID>
FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY_B64=<Base64-encoded string of Firebase private key>
FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL=<Firebase client email>
FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL=<Firebase database URL>
WARMUP_KEY=<Secret to trigger Firebase database warmup>
```

This is the [PR](https://github.com/JeffreyCA/spotify-recently-played-readme/pull/11) that I was working on.